# regex- using CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader to find nth instance of a word

Tags: python, regex, nltk, corpus

I have a corpus of newspapers as raw text files and I would like to be able to pull the editorials out of them. Most of the editorials start after the 3rd instance of the word "EDITORIAL" in all caps and end with the footer "sfbg".

My idea is to use python's regular expressions to extract these editorials. I'm using CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader.

I've tried looking for a list of CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader's methods myself, but I've come up empty.

Comment: `(.*?EDITORIAL){3}(.*?)sfbg`

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I'm still pretty new to programming in general and I haven't quite got my syntax nailed down.

Answer (score 1):

well, the regex to find the text "after 3rd instance of the word EDITORIAL and before the ending delimiter 'sfbg'" is:

`(.*?EDITORIAL){3}(?<content>.*?)sfbg`

Here's the consituent parts:

`(.*?EDITORIAL){3}` - finds everything up to the third use of the word "EDITORIAL" by using a non-greedy (safer - avoids matching too mutch) wildcard `.*?` and multiplying the whole group with `{3}`.

`(?<content>.*?)` - named match group "content". this is the match you want, it simply matches until....

`sfbg` - the ending delimiter.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/7yWWNX/1)

Comment: Would that code go after a method of regex?

ex: `re.find(.*?EDITORIAL){3}(?<text>.*?)sfbg`  ?